# Compression in MongoDb 3.2 does not work

Tags: mongodb

I installed MongoDb 3.2, and configured `snappy` compression in mongodb configuration file:

```
   engine: wiredTiger
   wiredTiger:
       engineConfig:
           cacheSizeGB: 99
           journalCompressor: none
       collectionConfig:
           blockCompressor: snappy
       indexConfig:
           prefixCompression: true
```

However I do not think compression actually work as I could see average object size in the collection is about the same (I filled collection created from scratch by the same objects right after configuration change and service restart):

- MMAPv1 no-compression avgObjSize: 5kb
- WiredTiger snappy avgObjSize: 4kb
- WiredTiger zlib avgObjSize: 4kb

when I run stats on collection here is what I see for "snappy":

```
"compression" : {
        "compressed pages read" : NumberInt(0), 
        "compressed pages written" : NumberInt(5), 
        "page written failed to compress" : NumberInt(0), 
        "page written was too small to compress" : NumberInt(4), 
        "raw compression call failed, additional data available" : NumberInt(0), 
        "raw compression call failed, no additional data available" : NumberInt(0), 
        "raw compression call succeeded" : NumberInt(0)
    },
```

for zlib:

```
{
    "compressed pages read" : NumberInt(0), 
    "compressed pages written" : NumberInt(1), 
    "page written failed to compress" : NumberInt(0), 
    "page written was too small to compress" : NumberInt(3), 
    "raw compression call failed, additional data available" : NumberInt(0), 
    "raw compression call failed, no additional data available" : NumberInt(1), 
    "raw compression call succeeded" : NumberInt(2)
}
```

Not sure how to read this info, and not sure how can I detect what's wrong with compression.

I should also say I had only few (like 10) objects in each scenario. Would it be enough to accurately measure average object compression ratio?

Comment: You can measure compression using db.stats(1024*1024).dataSize + db.stats(1024*1024).indexSize mentioned https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/new-compression-options-mongodb-30
In order to perform compression ratio accurately you add a huge chunk of data.

Comment: avgObjSize is more accurate for databases with different amount of objects as it is calculated as dataSize/count. Once I have similar amount of objects in datbases, dataSize is very similar for all this 3 scenarios as well, it's inside 15-20% difference between MMAPv1 and  WiredTiger, zlib is very close to snappy

Comment: I've sent the same question here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148139/compression-in-mongodb-3-2-does-not-work